# Pass attributes or options to backbone model

Tags: backbone.js

I'm not getting any attributes or options in model. I need to pass a route number to it in order to build a url. anyone see what im missing or how I should be doing this? I tried setting the attribute I want on the model but it's not in the model when I try to grab it.

view

```
define([
'text!html/tplDirection.html',
'models/direction',
'core'
], function (template, Direction) {

return Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '',
    template: _.template(template),
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.model = new Direction();       
        this.model.set({rtnm: options.routeNumber});
        console.log(this.model);
    },
    setup: function (routeNumber) {
        var self = this;
        // self.model.set({rtnm: routeNumber});
        $.when(self.model.fetch())
            .done(function () {
                console.log(self.model.toJSON());               
                self.render();
            })
            .fail(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log('request for data has failed');
            });         
    },

    render: function () {
    var data = {
        model: this.model.toJSON()
    };
        this.$el.html(_.template(template, data));
    },
```

Model

```
define([    
'core'
], function () {

return Backbone.Model.extend({

initialize: function (attributes, options) {       
    console.log(attributes);
},

/*  model: Routes,*/
//url: '/apiproxy.php?method=getdirections&rt=',

  parse: function (data) {
    var parsed = [];
        $(data).find('dir').each(function (index) {
        var dir = $(this).find('dir').text();           
        parsed.push({
            dir: dir,               
        });        
    });
    return parsed;
},

fetch: function (options) {
    options = options || {};
    options.dataType = "xml";
    return Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
}
});

});
```

Comment: You have any errors in browser console?

Comment: no but console.log(attributes) is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by passing options to model on instantiating. What confused me is that they come through as attributes and not options in the model. How come?

view:

```
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.model = new Direction(options);
    },
```

model:

```
initialize: function (attributes, options) {
    console.log(attributes);

},  
url: function () { 
    //'this' now contains attributes
    var route =  this.get("routeNumber);
    //var route =  this.attributes.routeNumber;
    return '/apiproxy.php?method=getdirections&rt=' + route;      
},
```